# Float button under the dynamic content

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a table with variable number of rows according to data fetched from server
If the table contains more than X rows it becomes scrollable
I want to add "floating" button that either

- Acts as a fake last row if theres too little rows to be scrollable
- Ovelays last row if table is scrollable

Im doing this in React and im able to obtain coordinates of last row of table
e.g
`let nodeBoundaries = document.getElementById('id').getBoundingClientRect()`

but im unable to position it with css

what i have tried is something like :

```
let rect = document.getElementById('lastRow').getBoundingClientRect()
    <div style={
      {'position' : 'fixed', 
      'left' : rect.left + 'px',
      'top' : rect.top+'px', 
      'height' : '20px', 
      'width':'50px', 
      'backgroundColor' :"red"}}>BUTTON </div>
      }
```

Comment: Why can't you just place the button below the table?

Answer (score 0):

as Tom said, you can try this and if table height is more than X you then can change button style to another property that matches your needs.

I also would like to point you to [FLEXBOX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) . IMO, a much cleaner way to achieve this.